# The Companions of the Messenger of Allah being always in a state of worry

Tags: hadith, sahaba, deeds

On more than one occasion, I have heard that the companions of the Messenger of Allah (piece be upon him) used to be in constant worry with respect to whether they intentions were pure, or whether their deeds would be accepted, etc.

Is there a narration from the companions on this matter which found its way in the six hadith books?

Comment: Mostly it is rather the fear from hypocrisy not impurity of intentions that is mentioned.

Comment: I think, at the end of the day, both are more or less the same, if not *the* same. However, my point was not whether it was this that or the exact wording, but whether there this matter is mentioned in sahih hadith collections.